# How to recognize non-human users?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2015, query-expressions

Listing all the users in the system, I noticed that some of them were system users and didn't have e.g. working hours at all. At the moment, I just list them and exclude from my loop my it's a Q&D approach and I prefer to do it right.

I haven't found any specific information on the *systemuser* entity that'd tell me if a certain one is a real profile (i.e. created in the Office 365 portal) or one that's provided my MS by default.

The Q&D code is as follows.

```
QueryExpression userQuery = new QueryExpression { EntityName = "systemuser", ... };
IEnumerable<Entity> users = service.RetrieveMultiple(userQuery).Entities;

IEnumerable<String> automatics = new[] { "INTEGRATION", "Support User", "SYSTEM" };
  foreach (Entity user in users.Where(element
    => !automatics.Contains(element.GetAttributeValue<String>("fullname")))) { ... }
```

Second best solution, if there's no way to determine who's on the automatics list and who's a real dude, is to make an exhaustive comprehensive list of exceptions. Once again, my google-fu failed me, as I haven't found any documentation on the full list of automatically created instances of the entity *systemuser*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach would be checking the `CreatedBy` field; which is `NULL` for users `SYSTEM` and `INTEGRATION`. This field is also `NULL` for the *CRM administrator user*, so you should consider excluding the admin user if it is actively being used by a human.

```
FilterExpression humanFilter = new FilterExpression();
humanFilter.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("createdby", ConditionOperator.NotNull));

if (retrieveAdminUser)
{
  humanFilter.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.Or;
  humanFilter.AddCondition(
    new ConditionExpression("domainname", ConditionOperator.Equal, "admin@crm"));
}

userQuery.Criteria.AddFilter(humanFilter);
```

Comment: For heads-up about the admin user +1.